# hikvision camera lag problem,How can I eliminate lag?

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, rtsp, ip-camera

I use Hikvision  DS-2CD1047G0-LUF 4 Mp brand IP camera to process the image with OpenCV, but the image has a delay of 1-2 seconds.

```
import cv2
 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:test1234@192.168.1.64/1")
# IP kamerası RTSP URL'si

 
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    cv2.imshow("IPCam", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

By the way, there is no lag in hikvision's web browser.

I tried changing the settings in hikvision's configure section. I lowered the resolution and set it to UDP but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe this is decoding lag? Which format has your stream - JPEG/MJPEG or H264/H265?

Comment: debug with something other than OpenCV

Comment: @elmir 
It shows jpeg in the configuration and I tried both h.264 and 265.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz can you explain a little more?

Comment: debug with VLC, ffmpeg, ... anything else

Comment: vlc also has the same problem.

Comment: I tried ffmpeg and gstreamer and the lag still persists.